# How to test a function passed to another component?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

How do I write a unit test to cover the logic in `fooFunction`?

The logic could be moved out to another file in order to achieve test coverage, but what if I don't want to?

`FooComponent.jsx`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import FooContext from './FooContext';
import BarComponent from './BarComponent';

function FooComponent() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();

  const fooFunction = inputValue => {
    setValue(inputValue * 2);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <span>Hello world!</span>
      <BarComponent inputFunc={fooFunction} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default FooComponent;
```

How do I test it? Is the only option to not declare the function inside the FooComponent scope?

Comment: function components are usually meant to be tested in blackbox, so you don't (or at least shouldn't have access to the function) --
You can turn this to a class component and expose this as a method. It can be useful if the logic is very complex. -- 
If it's not complex, then just interact with the UI so you can trigger this function

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel Given I wanted to have 100% code coverage, how would I structure this code?

Comment: Coverage is pointless in this case. Do you even know how this function is used ?

Comment: What's `fooFunc`? Can you provide a minimal completed reproducible code?